# Random value, Distribution function

Tags: probability

i dont understand what does it mean $F(\xi)$ where is F - continuous distribution function of random value $\xi$. Is it $P(\xi < \xi) = 0?$

Comment: Do you need further explanations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last question answer is: No. 
Define probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ and $\xi:\Omega \to\mathbb R$ is a random variable. Then it's (left-continuous as in your post) CDF is
$$
F(x)=\mathbb P(\xi<x)=\mathbb P\{\omega\in\Omega~:\xi(\omega)<x\}.
$$ 
Random variable $F(\xi)$ is a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$ too. For every $\omega_0\in\Omega$, 
$$
F(\xi(\omega_0)) = \mathbb P\{\omega\in\Omega~:\xi(\omega)<\xi(\omega_0)\}
$$

In other words, you firstly found what is a chance of $\xi$ to be less than any given $x$. Then if $\xi$ takes some value $\xi(\omega_0)$, we return the chance of $\xi$ to be less than this fixed value.

Say, for $\xi$ with exponential distribution with mean $1$, $F(x)=1-e^{-x}$ for $x\geq 0$. So $F(\xi)=1-e^{-\xi}$ a.s.